# Schwäbisch "neilaufa" - Herkunft der Bedeutung "das passt, das kommt zur rechten Zeit"

Tags: etymology, dialect, swabian

Im Schwäbischen hört man immer wieder den Begriff [neilaufa](http://www.norbertbaasner.de/woerterbuch/woerterbuch.php?buchst=n) in - soweit ich das überblicke - drei Bedeutungen:

> 1. Des Wasser muschd uff oimol **neilaufa** lasse - *Du musst das Wasser auf einmal hineinlaufen lassen*
> 2. Passed uff dass er net in de Mischd **neilaufed** - *Passt auf, dass ihr nicht in den Mist (hinein) tretet.*
> 3. Noi, mir **läuft** des grad net gut **nei**. Aber wenn's (bei) dir **neiläuft**, no isch's recht. - *Nein, das passt mir im Moment nicht so gut. Aber, wenn es bei dir passt, dann ist es gut.*

Die ersten beiden Bedeutungen sind auch im Standarddeutsch vertreten (hineinlaufen lassen, hineinlaufen/-gehen/-treten), aber die dritte Bedeutung ist offenbar eine völlig andere und kann nicht mit *[hineinlaufen](https://dwds.de/wb/hineinlaufen)* erklärt werden.

Hat jemand eine glaubhafte Erklärung für diese Bedeutung? Gibt es im Standarddeutsch oder in anderen Dialekten eine Entsprechung?

Comment: Die ersten beiden Beispiele dürften "standardsprachliches Schwäbisch", das letzte "umgangs-/jugendsprachlich" (so's das denn in einem Dialekt gibt) sein. Meine Eltern hätten (3) nicht verwendet.

Comment: Vgl. evtl. Hochdeutsch zuwiderlaufen?

Comment: @Philipp: eher das Gegenteil davon

Comment: Natürlich, aber auch mit laufen in bezug auf die Art und Weise

Comment: @tofro: das kann sein - meine Eltern haben das vermutlich auch nicht benutzt, aber ich selbst zähle mich nicht mehr so ganz zu den "Jugendlichen" ;)

Answer (score 3):

Für mich (mit biographischen Wurzeln im Schwabenland) hängt

> Dees lauft mr it guat nai!

semantisch zusammen mit

> Bua! Dees lauft guat naa!*

einem Ausspruch, den man unter Schwaben besonders zur Sommerzeit besonders nach anstrengenden körperlichen Aktivitäten (typischerweise Getreideernte oder Häuslebauen) besonders zum Anlass genussvollen Bierkonsums hört.

Sowohl das konkrete Bier beim "Naalaufa" wie auch die abstraktere Lebenssituation beim "Neilaufa" treffen auf eine dem Bier bzw. der Situation gegenüber hochgradig aufnahmebereite physisch-psychische Konstituiertheit des Subjekts. Das Subjekt saugt das fragliche Medium (Bier oder Situation) gleichsam von selbst in sich auf. "Dees lauft it guat nei" ist dementsprechend die Negation eines solchen Zustands.

---

*Oder die syntaktische Variante "Bua, lauft dees guat naa!"

Comment: Hmm - *naa*, *nab* oder *ra* sind aber schon etwas anderes. Ich denke nicht, dass es etwas damit zu tun hat.

Comment: Bei längerem Überlegen aber vielleicht doch... ?

Answer (score 1):

Eventuell lässt sich die Bedeutung erklären, wenn man nicht "hineinlaufen" als Grundlage des schwäbischen Ausdrucks nimmt, sondern "**einlaufen**". Das DWDS nennt [als vierte Bedeutung](https://dwds.de/wb/einlaufen):

> mit Hilfsverb ›ist‹:
>   (durch die Post) zugestellt werden, eingehen, eintreffen

Damit würde eine eintreffende Nachricht, die gerade zu den Umständen gut passt oder zur rechten Zeit kommt, eben "*gut neilaufa*". Eine eintreffende schlechte Nachricht oder unpassende Nachricht würde hingegen "*net gut neilaufa*".

Comment: Das habe ich zuerst auch gedacht, aber es ist ein trennbares Verb (deshalb habe ich auch dieses Beispiel gewählt), bei dem es eindeutig *nei* heißt und nicht *ei/oi* aber vielleicht hast sich das auch nur so entwickelt... ?